# How to recognize which pin was tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I got an app with `MKMapView` and large number of pins on this map.

Every pin got `rightCalloutAccessoryView`. I create it in this way:

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

How should i know, which pin was tapped? Thnx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `showDetails:` method, you can get the pin tapped from the map view's `selectedAnnotations` array.  Even though the property is an `NSArray`, just get the first item in the array since the map view only allows one pin to be selected at a time:

```
//To be safe, may want to check that array has at least one item first.

id<MKAnnotation> ann = [[mapView selectedAnnotations] objectAtIndex:0];

// OR if you have custom annotation class with other properties...
// (in this case may also want to check class of object first)

YourAnnotationClass *ann = [[mapView selectedAnnotations] objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"ann.title = %@", ann.title);
```

By the way, instead of doing `addTarget` and implementing a custom method, you can use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.  The annotation tapped is available in the `view` parameter:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"ann.title = %@", view.annotation.title);
}
```

Make sure you remove the `addTarget` from `viewForAnnotation` if you use `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`.

Comment: what if the title of 2 annotations is same ?

Comment: I know we can subclass and do, is there an easier method ?

Comment: @Anna, this really helped me.. Thanks +1