# How do I pass a string from my JSON map annotation to a button call in iOS?

Tags: ios, json

How do get the phone object from my array to the button on my map annotation call out?

I have the pins loading from a JSON array just fine and I am parsing out the address from the phone number.  How do I get the correct phone number to the button when that call out is pushed?

```
      for(id key in json) {
            id value = [json objectForKey:key];
            NSString *titlePin = [value valueForKey:@"address"];
            NSString *addressPhone = [value valueForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *latitude = [value valueForKey:@"latitude"];
            NSString *longitude = [value valueForKey:@"longitude"];

            NSArray* foo = [addressPhone componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
            NSString* justAddress = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
            NSString* phone = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];

            double myLatitude = [latitude doubleValue];
            double myLongitude = [longitude doubleValue];

            MKCoordinateRegion location1;
            location1.center.latitude =myLatitude;
            location1.center.longitude= myLongitude;
            location1.span.longitudeDelta=0.1;
            location1.span.latitudeDelta =0.1;

            MapAnnotation *ann1 =[[[MapAnnotation alloc] init] autorelease];
            ann1.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titlePin];
            ann1.subtitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",justAddress];
//EDIT added this line for part of sollution
     ann1.phone=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phone];
            ann1.coordinate= location1.center;
            [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
        }
    }
}

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
    MyPin.draggable = NO;
    MyPin.highlighted = YES;
    MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return MyPin;
}

-(void)button:(id)sender {

    // Call the phone number here!!!!!!!
    //NSLog(@"Button action: %@",phone);

}
```

MapAnnotaion.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *phone;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *phone;

@end
```

MapAnnotaion.m

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, phone;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [phone release];
    [super release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: you can subclass the MKAnnotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of codes from apple sample code :MapCallouts

**SFAnnotation.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface SFAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    UIImage *image;
    NSNumber *latitude;
    NSNumber *longitude;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;

@end
```

**SFAnnotation.m**

```
#import "SFAnnotation.h"

@implementation SFAnnotation 

@synthesize image;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = 37.786996;
    theCoordinate.longitude = -122.419281;
    return theCoordinate; 
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return @"San Francisco";
}

// optional
- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return @"Founded: June 29, 1776";
}

@end
```

where the title is the string shows in the call out's title

Edit 1

```
-(void)button:(id)sender {

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

MKAnnotationView *annotationView = button.superview.superview;

MapAnnotaion *mapAnnotaion = annotationView.annotation;

NSLog(@"%@", mapAnnotation.phone);


// Call the phone number here!!!!!!!
//NSLog(@"Button action: %@",phone);
```

}

Comment: May be I am saying what I want wrong.  I can set the title and the subtitle just fine. What I cannot seem to do is take the phone for the annotation and pass it to the -(void)button:(id)sender method for the pin that has a call out open when the button is pushed.

Comment: @Rick Do you want to call an action when the call out button is pressed?

Comment: yes and I am. I can log a "button pressed" with no problem.  How do I get the "phone" string from the correct array object to log?

Comment: Sorry if I seem a little needy but I get an error on the button.superview.superview;  Incompatible pointer types initializing MKAnnotationView with an expression of type UIView.  then my log comes us null

Comment: @Rick Try to nslog "button.superview", "button.superview.superview" and "button.superview.superview.superview" to find out which one is an MKAnnotationView

Comment: <MKPinAnnotationView: 0x6e2b180; frame = (574345 787771; 32 39); layer = <MKLayer: 0x6e2ded0>> visible:1 +40.80153100, -81.40566100   is  button.superview.superview

Comment: MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = button.superview.superview; I think this will work.

Comment: Great this worked. I also forgot to add the phone to the ann1 up top.  I still get a warning of Incompatible pointer types but it still works . Ill just keep hacking away at that part.  thanks

Comment: Rather than accessing superviews (which depends on _assuming_ the view layout is in a specific order), it's safer to use the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped).  Even better is to use the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method instead.