# UIButton added to UIButton not responding to selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have **added an ui button to a disclouser button**

And implemented selector method

but the action selector doesn't respond to the button why and what to do

```
//To add a discloser button to show route map
UIButton *detailBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=detailBtn;
[detailBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
DisplayMap *ann=(DisplayMap *)annotation;
detailBtn.tag = ann.detailButtonTag;


UIButton *btnOnPopup=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(- 207, -6, 300, 43)];
btnOnPopup.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[btnOnPopup addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnOnPopup.tag = ann.detailButtonTag;
btnOnPopup.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[detailBtn insertSubview:btnOnPopup aboveSubview:detailBtn];
```

the selector

```
[btnOnPopup addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(Second button btnOnPopup) is not working.

Comment: wich of them is not working ?

Comment: second button btnOnPopup

Comment: can you post showRoute2:

Comment: Why are you adding a button as a subview of a button?  The built-in callout view doesn't support accessory views larger than about 32 pixels.  _An unrelated comment_: I do not recommend using button tags to identify annotations since the map view provides much easier, elegant and reliable ways to do that.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876042/annotation-details-after-detail-disclosure-pressed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped for examples.

Comment: Those three saved letters on "btn" make your code a pain to read and talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `btnOnPopup` is out of `detailBtn`'s bounds so touches won't even get to it. Adding a button to a button is not really a great practice anyway. Adding it to a button's superview might be a little bit better (and will make your touches work, but you might need to adjust frame)

```
[detailBtn.superview insertSubview:btnOnPopup aboveSubview:detailBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add view and tap gesture recognizer instead of button:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureHandler:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

...

```
[detailBtn addSubview:view];
```

...

```
- (void)tapGestureHandler:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // your code for tap handler is here
}
```

Comment: Still not gonna work if view is outside of `detailBtn`'s bounds.