# Assigning value to double - issue

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am assigning a value in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` to the double `Lat` and `Lon` and use it in the button action but I get the `Lat` and `Lon` value zero while the I can see the value in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` . So please where could be my issue?

H File:

```
@interface LocationViewController
  double Lat;
  double Lon;
}
```

M file:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{


Lat = [[view annotation]coordinate].latitude;
Lon = [[view annotation]coordinate].longitude;

NSLog(@"Lat: %f AND Lon %f", Lat, Lon); //The value is correct
}
```

---

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;

if(annotation != locationMap.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"myPin";

    pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[locationMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
        pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    pinAnnotation.enabled = YES;

    //instatiate a detail-disclosure button and set it to appear on right side of annotation
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;
}
return pinAnnotation;
}
```

---

```
-(void)infoButton:(id)sender{

  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", Lat,Lon,lat1,lon1];

  NSLog(@"Test %f AND %f", Lat, Lon); //Value of both are zero here. 

  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Comment: Are the values reset somewhere? Do you actually use the same _instance_ of LocationViewController? To check you can use `NSLog(@"%p", self);` (or extend your existing NSLogs). If the values are not the same, it's not the same instance.

Comment: I am not calling it in somewhere else. Yes I am I will check now

Comment: I am getting this value. 0x853de50 for the `NSLog(@"%p", self);`

Comment: not related but **please** don't use capitalized variable names

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Ok I will be careful about that, Thanks.

Comment: about the specific question, the code you showed is fine, so the issue should be elsewhere

Comment: Is the `self` value the same at the point where you set values and where you use them?

Comment: @PhillipMills How to check that?

Comment: Log the value in both places and see if it gives you the same number (object address).

Comment: @PhillipMills I can only `NSLog` the one in the `viewdidload` the others won't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not implement *both* the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate *and* a custom method for the accessory button -- do one or the other.

If you do both, the map view will call both and, in your case, the custom button method is getting called before the delegate method (and before `Lat` and `Lon` are set).

Using just the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method is recommended.

- Move the code currently in `infoButton:` to the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method
- Remove the `infoButton:` method
- Remove the `addTarget` line from `viewForAnnotation`

*Not recommended* but, if you want to use your custom `infoButton:` instead of the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method for some reason:

- Remove the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method
- In `infoButton:`, get a reference to the currently selected annotation using the `selectedAnnotations` property of the map view

See [How to recognize which pin was tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped) for a code example of the custom method option.