# Layout relation between MKAnnotationView and its rightCalloutAccessoryView has changed in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, mkannotationview

An `UIButton` is set to the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` of the `MKPinAnnotationView`, and it fires `btnClicked:` method. In iOS6, the layout relation between `MKAnnotationView` and its `rightCalloutAccessoryView` can be easily used to find the `MKPinAnnotationView` through  `MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[[button superview] superview];`. But in iOS7, the layout relation does not exist anymore.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
...

MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:tripStartAddrAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {            
        MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                              initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:tripStartAddrAnnotationIdentifier];
        customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        UIButton* rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
        [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosureUpMap.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosureDownMap.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(btnClicked:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return customPinView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
...
}


-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"superview 1 :%@",[sender superview]);
    NSLog(@"superview 2 :%@",[[sender superview] superview]);
    NSLog(@"superview 3 :%@",[[[sender superview] superview] superview]);
    NSLog(@"superview 4 :%@",[[[[sender superview] superview] superview] superview]);
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[[sender superview] superview];
    // the information contains in pin.annotation is necessary for the pushed view controller
...    
}
```

Log for iOS6:

```
2013-09-30 01:21:11.851 MyApp[6113:c07] superview 1 :<UICalloutView: 0x1e3df250; frame = (-246 -60; 320 70); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e3e0140>>
2013-09-30 01:21:11.851 MyApp[6113:c07] superview 2 :<MKPinAnnotationView: 0x1b649510; frame = (526 223; 32 39); layer = <MKLayer: 0x1b649570>> visible:1 +33.19910200, +120.45132100
2013-09-30 01:21:11.852 MyApp[6113:c07] superview 3 :<MKAnnotationContainerView: 0xb68b380; frame = (0 0; 640 640); autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb68b410>>
2013-09-30 01:21:11.852 MyApp[6113:c07] superview 4 :<MKScrollContainerView: 0xb68c8f0; frame = (-280 -72.5; 640 640); autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb68c980>>
```

Log for iOS7:

```
2013-09-30 01:44:22.835 MyApp[6226:a0b] superview 1 :<_MKSmallCalloutContainerView: 0xdbe5120; frame = (0 0; 222 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xdbe1f30>>
2013-09-30 01:44:22.836 MyApp[6226:a0b] superview 2 :<MKSmallCalloutView: 0x1c53a380; frame = (0 0; 222 57); layer = <CALayer: 0x1c546440>>
2013-09-30 01:44:22.837 MyApp[6226:a0b] superview 3 :<UIView: 0xdb14770; frame = (0 0; 222 57); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xdb147d0>>
2013-09-30 01:44:22.837 MyApp[6226:a0b] superview 4 :<_UIPopoverView: 0xdbfa4c0; frame = (-27 -57; 222 57); layer = <CALayer: 0xdbfa5a0>>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great reason to use the map view's own delegate method `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` instead of a custom method.

Even if the superview approach works in iOS 6 or earlier, it is generally a bad idea to rely on a specific view hierarchy.

The delegate method conveniently provides a reference to the annotation view from which you can get the annotation via `view.annotation` (no guessing or hoping or assumptions).

Remove the addTarget and replace the custom method with the delegate method.

If you *must* use a custom method instead of the delegate method, it's much more reliable to get the selected annotation from the map view's `selectedAnnotations` property instead of looking for superviews.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876042/annotation-details-after-detail-disclosure-pressed for code examples.