# UIImagePickerController from Mapkit Annotation?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a project where I load custom annotations from an SQLLite db into MapKit and a right call out that sends an email. What I'd like to achieve is to be able to present the user with a Image Picker (Camera or Camera Roll) by pressing the Info button in the annotation call out.

Can anyone help with this?

This is my Annotation code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

NSLog(@"show me");

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}
else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) 
{
    static NSString * const identifier = @"MyCustomAnnotation";

    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView)
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mycusomimage.png"];
    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

     [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openMail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

     return annotationView;
}
return nil;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far in the openMail: method?   What's the exact problem?  If the question is how to know which annotation was tapped, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9876255/467105 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462699/how-to-recognize-which-pin-was-tapped?lq=1 for suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anna, I already log which one is pressed but what I'd like to do it when the user presses the info button either image picker or action sheet to be displayed, does that make sense?

Comment: So have you tried presenting one of those?  What happens?  Show the code you tried in openMail:.